# Increment a value in Matlab upto a second value (1:n logic)

Tags: matlab, matrix, increment

I have a 2 Year-Columns in Matlab as shown below:

```
             % Col2 Is always greater than Col1
mat  = [2009 2012 ;
        2012 2012 ;
        2012 2013 ;
```

I need to do 2009:2012 for row1, 2012:2012 for row2, and so on....  This is not very easy as the size 1:N keeps changing for each pair.

```
FinalAns = [    2009
                2010
                2011
                2012           % -- 
                2012           % -- 
                2012
                2013      ] ;  % --
```

I cannot use a 'for' loop as the data size is very large and I was not successful in using `accumarray` for this.  A vectorized solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I'm unclear on what you want exactly - what do you mean Col1, Col1+1 ... up to Col2? Those are matrices ...

Comment: @Ansari --> I have edited the Q.  Hope its much more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you need:

```
n = size(mat, 1);
c = arrayfun(@(x) {mat(x, 1):mat(x, 2)}, 1:n);
FinalAns = [c{:}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use arrayfun to produce a cell matrix as follows:

```
>> Cells = arrayfun(@(a, b) {a:b}, Col1, Col2);
>> Cells{1}

ans =

        2009        2010        2011        2012

>> Cells{2}

ans =

        2012

>> Cells{3}

ans =

        2012        2013
```

You might find the cell matrix more convenient than the form you originally asked for, but if not here is how to convert it:

```
>> horzcat(Cells{:})

ans =

        2009        2010        2011        2012        2012        2012        2013
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
Col1 = [ 2009  ; 2012 ; 2012 ] ;
Col2 = [ 2012  ; 2012 ; 2013 ] ;

finalAnswer = zeros(sum(Col2 - Col1) + length(Col1),1);

curr=0;
for iter = 1:length(Col1)
    finalAnswer((curr+1):(curr + Col2(iter)-Col1(iter)+1)) = Col1(iter):Col2(iter);
    curr = curr + Col2(iter)-Col1(iter)+1;
end
```

There's still the for loop, but by preallocating `finalAnswer` as above you should get most of the gains you'd expect from a vectorized solution.